# Is there a way to see answers with the most votes?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, voting

A few minutes ago a found an **answer** that is definitely worth reading! It has 74 up-votes.
If I want to see **questions** with the most votes then I can see them by clicking on the 'votes' tab. Is there a way to see those questions whose answers have the most votes?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution, [Questions with highest rated answers](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20parent.ParentId,%20child.Title,%20parent.Score%20FROM%20posts%20AS%20parent,%20posts%20AS%20child%20WHERE%20parent.ParentId%20=%20child.Id%20ORDER%20BY%20Score%20DESC%20LIMIT%20500).
The only downside is you have to append the ID manually to the end of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/`

**Update**
As per Cletus' request, [Top Posts in Questions NOT CC Wiki](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20parent.ParentId,%20child.Title,%20parent.Score%20FROM%20posts%20AS%20parent,%20posts%20AS%20child%20WHERE%20parent.ParentId%20=%20child.Id%20AND%20child.IsWiki=0%20ORDER%20BY%20Score%20DESC%20LIMIT%20500)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't upvote this again.

Comment: Unfortunately 'Top Posts in Questions NOT CC Wiki' is not working anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of them are working anymore. (Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document.)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an updated version for the new data explorer: [Questions with highest rated answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1535/questions-with-highest-rated-answers)
. It ignores community wiki questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can check users with Great Answer from the Badges page, then on the user profile page, answers are sorted by number of votes

Answer (score 3):

God I wish there was.

It should also have the option to exclude CW answers since they're 90% noise.

I would **love** to see good **programming related** answers without all the Dilbert cartoons and wedding cakes.